# Angular Map an observable nested object to another object

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to map field from sub object in the response JSON to the parent object

I get the following response

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "file-1",
  "survey": {
    "identifier": 1,
    "displayedValue": survey-1
  }
}
```

I am trying to map the previous json to this Object

```js
import { Entity } from './entity';

export class File extends Entity {
    name: string;
    survey: Entity['identifier'];
    status: string;
}
```

Here is Entity class

```js
export class Entity {
    displayedValue: string;
    identifier: string;
}
```

and here is how I was trying to map it

```js
this.fileService.getFileById(this.fileId).subscribe(data => {
  this.file = data;
});
```

The file service method

```js
  public getFileById(fileId: string): Observable<File> {
    const getFileByIdURL = environment.backendBaseURL + 'files/' + fileId;
    return this.http.get<File>(getFileByIdURL);
  }
```

**I need the file.survey to contain the survey identifier**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can map it like below,

```
this.fileService.getFileById(this.fileId).subscribe(data => {
  const entity = new Entity();
  entity.displayedValue = data.survey?.displayedValue;
  entity.identifier= data.survey?.identifier;

  this.file = new file();
  this.file.survey = entity;
  this.file.status= 'what u want';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But what if I have multiple nested objects like the survey is there a more generic way to do them all automatically instead of doing it manually. Like in my code I wrote  "survey: Entity['Identifier']" like I am telling him it's an entity object but I only need it's Identifier

Comment: ok. Then u can use Interface or Types instead of classes and use ES6 Destructuring like mechanism by changing attribute to provide it in proper way

Comment: Would be a lot if I ask for an example. Thanks again

Comment: follow this https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/destructuring/